# Black screen after NVIDIA driver and afterwards problems

Tags: boot, nvidia, touchpad

I installed NVIDIA driver form additional drivers ( topmost that shows tested) . After reboot it showed ablack screen with a cursor blinking. To solve this I searched youtube for fix. Following a video I went to UEFI/bios setup screen then I chnaged graphic driver to another one ( I guess this one is used by windows) . The black screen problem was fixed but another problem arose.

1. touchpad not working
2. wifi/bluetooth adapter not found

Following another video I followed these steps:
There is an option "Additional options for ubuntu" on pre-login screen of ubuntu
clicking on it we have a list where :-choosing first option is same as normal start of ubuntu and clicking on third option - i guess it start it in some previous state and it fixes everything. But again starting normal the problem starts again.
so this is not permanent solution.
So can anyone help me in this.
If i was not able to explain the problem clearly , please ask here.
Help me please please .
thanks in advance